# Something like personal.xlsb in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need use some functions in many sheets on Google Drive. Several users will use the functions of this script. 
In excel I have got personal.xlsb with macros to all files.
Have You any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Add-ons are the closest thing. You'll still have to enable them / "install" in each new document, but you won't have to reauthorize as you would if you simply copied a template script with a bound project.

Comment: Is it not possible to maintain functionality in any worksheet without installation?

Comment: It's part of Google's permission model. Just because you use add-on "A" once, does not mean add-on "A" should be used in every single document you ever made or make.

Answer (score -1):

You may check in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) the list of classes and methods you may use in Google Apps Script connected in your Google Sheets. The `Spreadsheet Service` allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files. See also the [guide to storing data in spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets/). Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on how Apps Script can interact with Google Sheets.

There's also a [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) about Google Sheets Macros that lets you record [macros](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004) that duplicate a specific series of UI interactions that you define.

Hope this helps!